# Too Many Audit Failure in Event Viewer Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a dedicated server and last week server has been hacked. I changed all of paswords to strongly and Change RDP Scope to my ip addresses.

When i enter the Event Viewer Security tab it is showing Too many Audit failure i show below.

[link to view image about question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs9cq.png)

You can see every 4-10 seconds my audit log is adding new audit failure. Is that hacking attempt or anything else? And if it is a hacking attempt how can i prevent this?

Comment: How about showing us the details of that event ID?

Comment: Was another user account created? Checked your users, make sure there all of them should be there? Event ID 4625 is not very useful without knowing the sub status code.

Comment: @enderaric:  have you had any answer for this?

Comment: @curiousBoy sorry but no..